# Of this most disgraceful imputation

Tags: meaning-in-context

**Of this most disgraceful imputation** we fully acquit Bacon.

- [archive.org,](https://archive.org/stream/anadvancedengli00oniogoog#page/n33/mode/1up) C.T. Onions, An Advanced English Syntax

What does the highlighted part mean? I guess ‘at the time of this most disgraceful im-putation of me’, we fully acquit Bacon’, it seems not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence has an inverted structure. It means:

> We fully acquit Bacon of this most disgraceful imputation.

In other words, Bacon was found not to have committed the disgraceful act that he was accused of committing (i.e. "this disgraceful imputation").

Comment: As to the essential part, the inverted structure, quite true. I'd quibble that the sentence is probably not intended to mean that Bacon was accused of committing the "disgraceful imputation", but that something disgraceful was imputed to Bacon. Note that "impute" means to attribute or assign something. In this context, "imputation" essentially means "accusation". You'd have to read the larger context, but it's likely he means that Bacon is innocent of the charge that was imputed to him, whatever that was, and not that the charge was that he falsely imputed something to someone else.

Comment: @Jay Thank you. I updated my post with your observation.